# На печать идет документ без Unicode символов, как так?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unicode, печать, принтер

При печати второй станицы вот этого документа - unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F600.pdf
Получается на выходе вод такое:

1) Печать из самого браузера
[image: Canon lbp6000 linux print unicode]
2) А вот это из Evince (Linux)
[image: Unicode print Canon lbp6000]

Впервые такое вижу, никогда бы не поверил, но своим глазам пришлось поверить.
Как это можно понять и как все таки это распечатать (Скриншоты не предлагать)?

Принтер Canon LBP6000, OC - Linux Debian (Ubuntu)
Драйвер с офф. сайта, все другое печатает нормально

Попробовал распечатать эту же страницу в Xpdf (Программа)
[image: XPDF linux]
И Ура на печать пошло то что мне нужно:
[image: Xpdf печать unicode lbp]

Теперь еще вопрос, это виноват драйвер или ПО ?

Comment: вероятно, это достаточно свежие поступления в стандарт, которые ещё не скоро попадут в распространённые шрифты. в просмотрщике pdf файл выглядит нормально?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да в просмотрщике все отлично, только на печать так пошло.

Comment: ну, значит, надо попробовать отправить на печать каким-то другим путём. например, с помощью `lpr`: `cat файл.pdf | lpr -P название-принтера`. если в системе есть дефолтный принтер, и печатаете на него, то можно опцию `-P ...` опустить. посмотреть список принтеров и какой определён дефолтным можно командой `lpstat -p -d`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin <(stdin)> Печать в НАЗВАНИЕ ПРИНТЕРА, после чего печать завершена

Comment: @alexanderbarakin пробовал еще так cat U1F600.pdf > /dev/lp и так pr -l60 U1F600.pdf | lpr не печатает так (

Comment: *это виноват драйвер или ПО ?* — тут как минимум четыре компонента: программа, отправляющая на печать → cups → проприетарный драйвер → проприетарная программа в принтере. методом отысылки на принципиально другой принтер, вы можете рассечь эту цепочку ровно пополам и определить виновную сторону.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin какими командами посылать на печать или что сделать чтобы понять какая сторона виновата ?

И еще момент программа может просто посылать на печать через цепочку №2 а не №1 как остальные или программа передает на печать совсем другим алгоритмом ?


Сори за такие вопросы, просто никогда не задумывался как идет печать на принтер - в каком виде (изнутри).

Из Xpdf я на печать отправлял так http://i.stack.imgur.com/UzVAQ.png через команду lp (По умолчанию там lpc), после чего во всплывающем сообщении было "<(stdin)> Печать в MyPrinter"

Comment: ну, если `lpr` (без параметров) отправил куда-то не туда, а `lp` (без параметров) отправил куда надо, то и пользуйтесь `lp`. / цепочки обработки и преобразований информации в процессе доставки до печатающей головки принтера могут быть весьма длинными. боюсь, я мало что смогу ещё рассказать по этому поводу. глобальные четыре этапа (для вашего случая) я уже назвал, методику «чистого» эксперимента для выяснения «виновной» половины из этих этапов — озвучил. дальше вы уже сможете сами экспериментировать/вникать.